# How to calculate fast in a given graph the probability that one of n non overlapping pairs of vertices wont be on an edge

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, probability, graph-theory

I have graph with 45 vertices, and I want to calculate the probability that if I take n random non overlapping pairs, one of the pair wont be on an edge.
When I say, non overlapping pair, I mean that they aren't sharing any vertex.

For example, with n == 2, and with this graph:

[image: Example For Graph]

The probability for the top left vertex to be selected is 4/5, then, if he was selected, the probability of it to be in a pair with the top right vertex is 1/4.

So the result should be (4/5)*(1-1/4)=0.6

The fastest way I could think about was to detect which vertex have the least neighbors and do a recursion on this vertex.

This is the code I wrote (in java)

```
public class TwinNeighbor {
    public static double get(byte[][] neighborsArr, int pairAmount) {
        return getRec(neighborsArr, pairAmount, new boolean[neighborsArr.length]);
    }

    private static double getRec(byte[][] neighborsArr, int pairAmount, boolean[] deleted) {
        int deleteAmount = total(deleted);
        if (pairAmount == 0)
            return 1;
        if (pairAmount * 2 > neighborsArr.length - deleteAmount)
            return 0;

        int index = getIndexWithLeastNeighbors(neighborsArr, deleted);
        double total = 0;
        deleted[index] = true;
        for (byte neighbor : neighborsArr[index]) {
            if (deleted[neighbor])
                continue;
            deleted[neighbor] = true;
            total += getRec(neighborsArr, pairAmount - 1, deleted);
            deleted[neighbor] = false;
        }
        double probabilityIfSelected = total / (neighborsArr.length - deleteAmount - 1);
        double probabilityIfNotSelected = getRec(neighborsArr, pairAmount, deleted);
        deleted[index] = false;

        double probabilitySelectCard = (double) pairAmount * 2 / (neighborsArr.length - deleteAmount);
        return probabilitySelectCard * probabilityIfSelected + (1 - probabilitySelectCard) * probabilityIfNotSelected;
    }

    private static int total(boolean[] arr) {
        int total = 0;
        for (boolean b : arr)
            if (b)
                total++;
        return total;
    }

    private static int getIndexWithLeastNeighbors(byte[][] neighborsArr, boolean[] deleted) {
        int minNeighborsAmount = neighborsArr.length;
        int minNeighborsIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < neighborsArr.length; i++) {
            if (deleted[i])
                continue;
            int neighborsAmount = 0;
            for (byte neighbor : neighborsArr[i])
                if (!deleted[neighbor])
                    neighborsAmount++;
            if (neighborsAmount < minNeighborsAmount) {
                minNeighborsAmount = neighborsAmount;
                minNeighborsIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return minNeighborsIndex;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(1 - TwinNeighbor.get(new byte[][] {
            {1},
            {0,2,3,4},
            {1,3,4},
            {1,2,4},
            {1,2,3}
    }, 2));//prints 0.6000000000000001
}
```

Is there any way to make my code run faster?

Edit:

And if n is small, is there a way to make it faster? (n <= 6, |V| = 45)

Comment: How fast does your code run?  What performance do you require?  Have you time profiled your code to find which part takes the longest to run?

Comment: The example i showed runs in 0.001669299s, the performance i need is somehing i will be able to run 200 millions time (i can let it run during nights), how can i make time profile?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the special case where n = |V|/2 amounts to counting the
number of perfect matchings, a #P-hard problem, so barring a miracle,
you're stuck with an exponential-time algorithm.

You could get an O(n |V| 2<sup>|V|</sup>)-time algorithm by
memoizing the result for each (induced subgraph, n′) pair where n′ ≤
n. That's expensive for |V| = 45 but not out of the question,
especially if n is small and you only have to evaluate the subgraphs
with ≤ 2n vertices missing.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question, is it solving the issue? I think that there is a way to make it O(|V|!/((|V|-2n)!*2^n))

Comment: @Ofek yes, but needing to run 200 million times is an obstacle. I'll think about it.

Comment: The idea is to create database for poker, and 200milions is the amount distinctive 2 cards in hand and 5 on table. and each node is a card that an opponent can have, most of the time the score is the highest card, so lot of vertex (any higher card) is **not** connected to every other vertex

Comment: @Ofek To confirm: the problem you're solving is, given a pair of cards in your hand, cards on the table, and the number of other players, what are the odds that you have the winning hand?

Comment: Yes, (i need to type 10 more characters)